# Allowing user to choose multiple input files in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I have built a basic model to run some calculations on a number of feature classes in Model Builder. These tools include Merge, Delete Identical, Make Table, Select Layer Attribute, Delete Rows and a Make XY event layer. Currently the model has a number of feature classes added directly to the model.

At the beginning, I would like the user to be able to choose which feature classes they add for processing. It should look like the options you get when using the Merge Tool in ArcMap where the user can browse to the files to be processed. The files could be anywhere on the PC and not necessarily in the same workspace.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set input as model paramater. When you execute the model you can specify input:

[image]

See: ["Creating model paramaters"](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/creating-model-parameter.htm)

If you want many inputs to a single tool, for example merge many inputs you can:

- Right click the blue input and select "A list of values"
- Or right click the model background - Create variable - Select Feature Class and check "Multivalue" checkbox.

Comment: Thank you :-) Yes, this makes sense, but is there a way to add 2, 3, 4,... files in a GUI like this?

Comment: Yes, look at the link

Comment: OK, i have looked at the link to "Creating model parameters" and the 'duplicate' post (my apologies for any duplication).Still, it does not give the required GUI. With 'Input datasets' blank and set as a parameter for a Merge tool I still only get the one drop down list as BERA showed above.

Comment: @user2224979 you want many inputs to a single tool? Right click blue input and select "A list of values". Or right click the model background - Create variable - Select Feature Class and check "Multivalue" checkbox.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I needed. Thank you so much.